# flex plugin on eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

This is not a programming question but i wanted to know How to install flex plugin for eclipse on ubuntu.Point me to any links for this.Eclipse is already installed.Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Builder is not supported on any form of Linux.

You might try [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/features/), which has support for [Linux](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FAQ#Does_FDT_run_under_Linux.3F).

IntelliJ also supports Linux, however is not eclipse based.

Answer (score 0):

You can make flash builder run in linux using wine. Intellij Is decent, but fall way short in flex development. ( except re factoring of course ;))

search google for "flexbuilder in linux" + wine. You will get multiple results including this one.

http://diariolinux.com/2009/06/22/how-to-install-flash-builder-on-linux/